# Tumblr Sticky Post in 2nd Position

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm hoping to get some help in updating the theme on my Tumblr to display "sticky" tagged posts as the 2nd post (not the 1st/at the top). Some of the code for the sticky posts is below...I'm pretty new to the platform, but this might be an easy question for someone else?

Thought I could just change the "1" position to "2", but doesn't seem to work.

```
<meta name="if:Sticky Posts" content="1">
```

Another section:

```
    {block:IfStickyPosts}
    .index article.{text:Sticky Tag} {
        display: none;
    }
    .index article.{text:Sticky Tag}.sticky-show,
    .index.tagged article.{text:Sticky Tag},
    .index.search article.{text:Sticky Tag} {
        display: block;
    }
    {/block:IfStickyPosts}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What theme are you using? Do you have a link to your live site?

Comment: I'm using the "hipster" theme. Live site is knightofpassage.com or knightofpassage.wordpress.com. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suggest contacting the Theme author for help with this.